# while I try to run basic Java code there was some variable scope error why it happens?

Tags: java

```
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sum;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            if (i == 9) {
                sum = 10;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

why this code gives this error?

> HelloWorld.java:9: error: variable sum might not have been initialized
> System.out.println(sum);

Comment: Your compiler will consider with every loop that it doesn't run at all and with every if statement that it is never entered because the condition might never be fulfilled. Hence the compiler can't guarantee that your initialization of `sum=10` is ever reached.

Answer (score 1):

We can look at the code and intuitively reason that `sum` will always have a value by the time it's used, because the loop will always execute and one of the iterations will satisfy the `if` condition.

But *the compiler* doesn't *intuitively reason* any of that.  It sees a loop and a conditional block and it can't *guarantee* that `sum` will have a value by the time it's used.  To the compiler, it's possible that loops may iterate 0 times or that conditions may never be `true`.

Basically, we can "test the code" in our heads and predict its outcome.  But the compiler doesn't test the code, no matter how simple the code may be.

You can correct the problem by simply initializing the value:

```
int sum = 0;
```

Comment: If we were to reason fully about that code, it would be clear the loop is entirely superfluous.  `int sum = 10` would do the entire job.  So it's not just the compiler only doing partial analysis :-)